# Linux C: Changing process name during compilation

Tags: c, linux, gcc

So I am trying to change the name of the process of the c program from crystal_capture to crystal_captured, it seems to be wanting to keep the old process name (crystal_capture) .

Here is the makefile.

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
MSFLAGS=-lpcap -I/usr/include/mysql -DBIG_JOINS=1  -fno-strict-aliasing  -g -L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -ldl
CAPTURE=crystal_captured

all: $(CAPTURE)

$(CAPTURE): parser.o $(CAPTURE).o
     $(CC) $(MSFLAGS) parser.o $(CAPTURE).o -o $@

$(CAPTURE).o: $(CAPTURE).cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(MSFLAGS) $(CAPTURE).cpp

parser.o: parser.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) parser.c

clean:
    rm -rf *.o $(CAPTURE)
```

**Commands**
    `make;
    sudo ./crystal_captured;
    ps -A | grep crystal`

**Seeing**
`crystal_capture`

So is there anyway I can change the process name from compiling, without having to go into the code.

Comment: "It seems to be wanting" is pretty vague. Exactly what happens, what output do you get? I would expect there to be permissions problems in writing to `/bin` on most systems, for instance.

Comment: This seems ok. It should produce /bin/program_name if you have permissions to write there (normally only root can do that). What's actually happening ? (Though, it's customary to output the executable to the current directory, and rather provide an install target that places the executable in e.g. the /bin folder)

Comment: @unwind @nos Yeah I am compiling to bin on purpose. I am going to create an install target to do that in the future, it's just not really needed right now. But either way all that is happening is that a new executable is showing up (with the new name) in /bin/. However when I run it and then run ` ps -A  ` it shows up with the old process name.

Comment: @dostrander: Is your program modifying `argv[0]` by any chance?

Comment: @Hasturkun no I do not

Comment: Please edit the question to show **exactly** the commands you're running, and the `ps` output.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Just did, let me know if there is anything else you need, and I appreciate the patience.

Comment: Silly question, but is the new name a longer suffix of the old name, as in your second edit? ie. is the name being shown a truncated version of the name? (truncated to 15 chars, possibly)

Comment: @Hasturkun the new name is 16 characters and the old name is 15 characters.

Comment: @dostrander, you have not shown the commands you're running. Stop showing "simplified" versions of your makefile that don't shown the significant details, and show the exact commands you're running to start the process and to run `ps`! I think Hasturkun is probably onto something with the length of the names. Have you tried changing it to a completely different name, to see if that works? Have you tried shorter names? Have you checked `/proc/$PID/exe` to see the process is using the right executable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some debugging and some help I finally figure it out. It wasn't doing anything wrong it was just truncating the 'd' that I added onto the name.

It must truncate it to 15 chars max.

Comment: Run `ps aux` or `ps -ef` instead of `ps -A`, that way you'll see the whole program name and more.

Answer (score 3):

Your makefile target is `$(NAME)` but it outputs to `/bin/$(NAME)` so will always try to rebuild the target. Also, writing to `/bin/` implies you're compiling as `root`, don't do that. You should output to the target's name:

```
$(NAME): $(NAME).o
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(NAME).o -o $(NAME)
```

The easiest way to do that is use the built-in `make` variable that refers to the target:

```
$(NAME): $(NAME).o
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(NAME).o -o $@
```

If you want the target to be in `/bin/` (which you should not do) then you can do:

```
/bin/$(NAME): $(NAME).o
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(NAME).o -o $@
```

But the target name and the file created should still match, or you're lying to `make`.

You can also use the built-in variable that refers to the first prerequisite:

```
$(NAME): $(NAME).o
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Your makefile is pretty pointless, given `program_name.c` you can compile a simple program without a makefile like so:

```
make CFLAGS=-Wall program_name
```

This will use `make`'s default rules to compile `program_name` from `program_name.c` using `gcc`

You haven't said what the problem is, so I don't know if it's related to difference between `$(NAME)` and `/bin/$(NAME)` but unless you rephrase the question it's not really possible to figure out what you are seeing and why you think it's wrong.

Unless the process alters `argv[0]` the process name is just the name of the executable, so if you execute `/bin/foobar` then the process name will be `/bin/foobar`. If you want to change it just change the name of the executable, that shouldn't be difficult.